# How to allocate image type while creating a dataporc cluster through gcloud command?

Tags: shell, apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-dataproc

I want to assign 1.4-ubuntu18 as the image type while creating a dataproc cluster through gcloud command. I could not find the format in which i am supposed to enter it so, just used the name but this seems to be generating the below error. What should i use in place of 1.4-ubuntu18?

```
> --image 1.4-ubuntu18 \

ERROR: (gcloud.beta.dataproc.clusters.create) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Error validating image '1.4-ubuntu18': Parameter image must conform to the pattern [a-z](?:[-a-z0-9]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?|[1-9][0-9]{0,19}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flag you are looking for is `--image-version` which takes an image version, e.g., `1.4-ubuntu18` or `1.4.25-debian9`.

`--image` takes an image URI instead of image version, e.g., `projects/my-project/global/images/my-image`, which is usually used for [custom images](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/guides/dataproc-images).

See `gcloud dataproc clusters create --help` for more details.